# Is this constructor initializer causing a dangling reference?

Tags: c++, reference, dangling-pointer

I'm studying the C++ Primer 4th edition by Stanley B. Lippman. In section 12.4.1, when the author talks about constructor initializers, he gives this example:

```
class ConstRef {
  public:
    ConstRef(int ii);
  private:
    int i;
    const int ci;
    int &ri;
};
// OK: explicitly initialize reference and const members.
ConstRef::ConstRef(int ii): i(ii), ci(i), ri(ii) { }
```

I suspect that this may cause a dangling reference `ri` pointing to `ii`, which is a temporary. Am I right?

Comment: clang++ is real helpful: `warning: binding reference member 'ri' to stack allocated parameter 'ii' [-Wdangling-field]`

Comment: Having googled around to see what it's like, the error report looks really great.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think so too. Try this

```
ConstRef::ConstRef(int ii): i(ii), ci(i), ri(i) { }
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply! So I'm more certain now :)